# Question about the concept of NFTs

Tags: contract-invocation

I think I understand the mechanics of the NFTs, but what I am wondering about is the following. Let's say I want to tokenize my new car. I want every 'bit' of maintenance on my car recorded on the blockchain. And even the ownership of the car. So, when I sell my car I transfer the ownership by selling 1 NFT to the new owner. But, now comes the part where I can't wrap my head around at the moment. I believe you can't put a PDF in the metadata of an NFT. So, how does that work then? And what happens - theoretically speaking - when I transfer the NFT, but I keep the car keys for myself... Does the new owner has a right of speaking when he goes to the police for instance?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe you can't put a PDF in the metadata of an NFT. So, how does that work then?

You are right, currently it does not work.

For provenance, or the documents of a maintenance history and past ownership, you do not need an NFT. It is enough that you have a persistent, long living storage.

[You can, for example, create a folder for your cars on a persistent storage chain like Arweave](https://www.arweave.org/).

In theory you could also put PDFs to Ethereum blockchain, but it would cost you more than million dollars per PDF. So it is better to use a chain that is specialised to this use case.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Lets say I finally manage to store all the mainenance history and past ownership on a chain like Arweave. Is the data publicly available or only for the current owner?

Comment: At that point, it can be either public or private, Arweave is flexible.

https://ardrive.io/what-is-arweave/

Comment: Interesting. I still find it hard to wrap my head around the possibilities. I am thinking too pragmatic I think. I read somewhere that, for instance, the transport of sea containers from one country to another country currently has a lot to do with many intermediaries who take care of the paperwork involved. I don't see how blockchain technology can eliminate those intermediaries. Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: StackExchange comments section is not good place to ask further questions. Also your question is specific to maritime industry. I suggest you seek answer from maritime experts.